# How to pass value to SQL Query in Data Environment's Command Object at run-time in Visual Basic 6.0?

Tags: vb6

In DataEnvironment I have a Command Object in which I have
given following SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE Date = Todays_date
```

Here `Todays_date` is a public variable in Module.
This variable accepts value at run-time.

How to call variable in DataEnvironment's SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB6 manuals cover this in *Closing and Reopening the Recordset* under the heading [Data Environment Programming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716181%28v=VS.60%29.aspx).  The example given there looks like:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    ' You must close the recordset before changing the parameter.
    If DataEnvironment1.rsCommandQuery.State = adStateOpen Then
        DataEnvironment1.rsCommandQuery.Close
    End If
    ' Reopen the recordset with the input parameter supplied by
    ' the TextBox control.
    DataEnvironment1.CommandQuery Text1.Text
    With Text2
        .DataField = "AU_LName"
        .DataMember = "CommandQuery"
        Set .DataSource = DataEnvironment1
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' Supply a default value.
    Text1.Text = "172-32-1172"
    ' Change the CommandButton caption.
    Command1.Caption = "Run Query"
End Sub
```

You call the Command object as a method of its parent DataEnvironment, passing the parameters there.  Gotta love The Fine Manual.